# Difficulties with asynchronous requests in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Since few days Im struggling through my application and problems associated with few http requests.

I've shown everything inside plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tM9RPL5fxpDqiRqbOF4A?p=preview

But briefly speaking, everything works until the third http request comes in. It doesn't load data properly from the files. It should take up data from json for every point from the `_watchlistElements` variable and drop it inside the `_values` variable.

If you look inside the plunker code, you will easily get what's exactly my problem. I have put much work into this plunker code to make it work and describe everything in an easy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **three** problems:

1. You are calling the getValues function not in the right place.
2. You response from getValues http call are objects, not an array.
3. Your files name are not correct.

This is the solution:

```
export class App implements OnInit {
 private _items: Array<WatchlistComponent> = [];


  constructor(@Inject(Http) private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('items.json')
        .subscribe(res => this._items = res.json()); //returns names of the lists, e.g. WL_616873
  };

  private _watchlistElements: Array<WatchlistComponent> = [];


  private updateWatchlistTable(xid) {
    this._watchlistElements = [];
    this.http.get(xid + '.json')
        .subscribe(res => {
          this._watchlistElements = res.json();
          this.getValues();
        });
  }


  private _values: Array<WatchlistComponent> = [];



  private xid: string;

  private getValues() {
    this._values = [];
    this._watchlistElements.map(v => 
    this.http.get(v.xid + '.json')
        .subscribe(res =>{
           this._values.push(res.json());
        }));
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getValues();
  }

}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ktOhjZ9J1a8UgVlEUhow?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

When the selection is changed, just update the values array:

```
private updateWatchlistTable(xid) {
console.log(xid);
this._watchlistElements = [];
this.http.get(`${xid}.json`)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this._watchlistElements = res.json();
        this.getValues();//add this
    }
      ); }
```

Let me know if it worked, I tested but i have a some 404 because json files it does not exist in your plunker.

Greetings!!

Comment: Thank you for your good intentions but unfortunately it doesnt change anything :(

Comment: can you update the plunker adding this `.subscribe(res => {this._watchlistElements = res.json();this.getValues();});`in the line 44 and upload the json files DP_019908 , DP_018829, DP_018690 , for keep trying